# Typescript Global Variable

Tags: typescript, global-variables

I'm struggling to understand the correct way to expose a variable in Typescript across multiple files.  I've read a few existing questions on StackOverflow, but many seem to be for older version (1.0) of Typescript.

Given I have a project with multiple packages compiled using lerna and within the package `common` I want to declare a variable `token` which can be read/write by files in other packages, how should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you're using modules anyway, you're likely to have much less pain using a variable exported from a module as compared to a true global variable.  Because TypeScript treats imports themselves as read-only (in line with ECMAScript), you can't just export a variable and have other modules write directly to it.  Instead, you can export an object and use a (writable) property of that object to hold your token.  For example:

```
// common/index.ts
export const tokenHolder = {token: undefined};

// another file
import { tokenHolder } from "common";
tokenHolder.token = "foo";
console.log(tokenHolder.token);
```

If this wasn't what you were looking for, please clarify the question.